# How to install vncserver for multiple remote desktop users on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

Tags: server, vnc

I found [this guide](https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-install-vnc-server-on-ubuntu-14.04) online, but it's related to Ubuntu 14. It doesn't work with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

I'm trying to set up a Ubuntu 18 dedicated for multiple remote users (and independent session) with a desktop-like environment

The above guide works only for one remote user, but I need more than one simultaneously.

i find out any user can access to other profile !!
that's a serious issue to me !

Can you guide me how to do it for the new 18.04 LTS?
creating vncserver or anything else which allow more than one user simultaneously connect to a remote ubuntu 18.04 system - only his profile -

thx again !

Answer (score -1):

A vnc server has the permissions of the user who runs it.  I would start a VNC session for each user that wants a connection.  Simply run the vncserver with a different port numbers for each user (e.g. Fred is with "su fred -c 'vncserver :1;", Nancy is "su nancy -c 'vncserver :2'").  Each time vncserver is run, it will ask to setup a unique password for that user.

However, I'm not sure that vncserver is the solution you're looking for, you may want to check out other remote desktop applications that manage sessions more intuitively.

Comment: I find out a user can remotely access someone else Home directory ! We dont want that, obviously. vncserver is the only app i know for a remote control thru Ubuntu. Is there any other more intuitive and easier way to handle such work ? my linux KB is limited. I appreciate if you have a better suggestion, if you can forward me to a guide. i need to let dozen users to remotely access ubuntu 18.04, they are allowed to access all apps installed, but every home must be specific to each remote users, i mean a user should not be able to spoof someone else home directory. Thx!

Comment: Its quite possible to run a multi-user VNC server with users authenticating via xdm (or similar).